# SQL Select of data from three tables relationed

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I Have three tables:

```
*orders:

  -id (PK)

  -iduser (FK)

  -date



*detail_orders:

  -id(PK)

  -or_id (FK of id on orders)

  -prod_id (FK of id on products)

  -price

  -quantity


*products:

  -id (PK)

  -description
```

There is a table of **orders**, another of the **detail** (the products, prices, quianties) of the order and another to retrieve the **description of the product**.

I want to get this using mysql from a specific iduser (retrieved from php):

```
order.id | order.date:

products.description | orders.quantity | orders.price
products.description | orders.quantity | orders.price
products.description | orders.quantity | orders.price

... (etc while there are products on this order)
```

How should be the query? I've experience retrieving data from only one sql table and no joining data from more than one.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service. You need to do your own studying to learn the basics of SQL joins.

Comment: @Barmar Sory, I forgot to write that I was reading about JOIN and I understand the concept, but when there are more than two tables envolved I couldn't do it.

Comment: Show what you tried, and then we can help you understand what you did wrong. There's no significant difference with 3 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `JOIN` the tables, like this:

```
SELECT products.description, orders.quantity, orders.price
FROM detail_orders
  INNER JOIN products ON (products.prod_id = detail_orders.prod_id)
  INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.id = detail_orders.or_id)
```

If you want to query for a specific user:

```
    SELECT products.description, orders.quantity, orders.price
    FROM detail_orders
      INNER JOIN products ON (products.prod_id = detail_orders.prod_id)
      INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.id = detail_orders.or_id)
    WHERE orders.iduser = someUser
```

Comment: It was useful to solve my problem. Thanks you very much.